# Facebook web SDK - identify user has clicked close button on facebook login popup

Tags: facebook, web, sdk

I am using facebook web SDK in my application for single signon. Consider following scenario - 
- user logs in to facebook
- User launches our application. Clicks on login using facebook button (custom button). On click of button calling method FB.login(.........)
- popup for facebook login is displayed (popup by facebook SDK). As user is already into facebook in other tab, login popup prompts for password.
- User clicks on close button (top bar x button).
- Though user has clicked on X button, FB.login call returns success with response.status as "connected"

my Issue is i want to identify user has clicked on cancel button, so that custom action can be taken. Basically i would like to identify user has clicked on close/cancel button. thanks in advance.

Comment: _“As user is already into facebook in other tab, login popup prompts for password”_ - in that case it should _not_ ask for a password, _because_ the user is already logged in to Facebook.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.we are getting password prompt. my issue is around how to identify user has clicked popup window close button.

Comment: Are you specifically asking the user to re-enter their password then? Otherwise, this should not happen in the first place. And I don’t think you can get the info that the user merely closed the popup. You would get the info if they explicitly cancelled from within the login dialog ... but not if they just close the popup. Why do you need to react to that anyway?

Comment: My code flow depends on response status. So if response status is "connected" it means user has successfully logged in.  Based on response status I am making subsequent service calls. Issue occurs as even if user clicks on popup close button response status comes as "connected" hence the issue, my service calls are still triggered.

Comment: If they logged in to your app before and granted it all requested permissions, then they _are_ connected to your app as soon as you perform that check, as long as they are logged into Facebook as well. So what is the _actual_ issue? Do your service calls fail, because of a missing/invalid token, or what?

Comment: Actual issue is UI behavior - As soon status comes as connected, I make store the token and make service call and refresh the page. in the UI user is shown as "logged in". it's user experience - though user clicked on cancel still my flow continues and user is shown as "logged in" in my application. Expectation is - once user clicks on close button on facebook popup process should stop.

Comment: You still have not answered my question whether you specifically did anything to make it ask already logged-in users for their password again - because by default that would not happen. Unless you did, your users should not even have a chance to close the popup - because it will do that _by itself_ already in such a case.

Comment: sorry about delayed response. I did not do anything specifically to make user enter their password.